# Bson ignore field

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, bson, database

I have class **Salesman**

```
public class Salesman
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("complementTime")]
    public DateTime ComplementTime { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("futureWorker")]
    public FutureWorkerInfo FutureWorker { get; set; }
}
```

and class **Consultant**

```
public class Consultant
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("complementTime")]
    public DateTime ComplementTime { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("futureWorker")]
    public FutureWorkerInfo FutureWorker { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("recommendedWorkers")]
    public FutureWorkerInfo[] RecommendedWorkers { get; set; }       
}
```

Both of this classes has class

```
 public class FutureWorkerInfo
{
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("homeAddress")]
    public FutureWorkerHomeAddress HomeAddress { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("secondPhone")]
    public string SecondPhone { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("birthDate")]
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

And i need ignore field "homeAddress" when i use class "Salesman". It's mean that i don't must insert or read from mongo database this field when only in Salesman. When i use Consultant i should 'can' some opertaions with field "homeAddress".

Comment: You could try creating another class that would inherit `FutureWorkerInfo` (e.g. `ExtendedFutureWorkerInfo`), move the `HomeAddress` field to this new class and remove from `FutureWorkerHomeAddress`. Then in `Salesman` you would use existing class, and in `Consultant` - new one. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thx, but no, i need stay with common entity

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with interfaces.

Create an ISalesmanFutureWorkInfo

```
public interface ISalesmanFutureWorkInfo
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Phone { get; set; }
    string SecondPhone { get; set; }
    string Email { get; set; }
    string BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

Create an IConsultantFutureWorkInfo that has the HomeAddress and inherits ISalesmanFutureWorkInfo

```
public interface IConsultantFutureWorkInfo : ISalesmanFutureWorkInfo
{
    FutureWorkerHomeAddress HomeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Change your classes to use the interfaces.

```
public class Consultant
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("complementTime")]
    public DateTime ComplementTime { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("futureWorker")]
    public IConsultantFutureWorkInfo FutureWorker { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("recommendedWorkers")]       
    public IConsultantFutureWorkInfo[] RecommendedWorkers { get; set; }
}

public class Salesman
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("complementTime")]
    public DateTime ComplementTime { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("futureWorker")]
    public ISalesmanFutureWorkInfo FutureWorker { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. looks nice:)

Answer (score 0):

```
[BsonElement("homeAddress")]
[BsonIgnoreIfNull]
public FutureWorkerHomeAddress HomeAddress { get; set; }
```

Right now everything is okay